# nvcc error on ubuntu 11.10 "don't know what to do with..."

Tags: ubuntu, cuda, nvcc

I've tried to install the cuda toolkit 5.0 on ubuntu 11.10. I think the installation went well
I'm trying to test it by running the deviceQuery example. But when I run nvcc deviceQuery from the command line i get the error: nvcc fatal   : Don't know what to do with 'deviceQuery'

Does anyone know why i'm getting this issue.

Comment: Are you trying to compile the deviceQuery sample or run it?  If you're trying to run it, you don't use nvcc (a compiler driver) to run it.  You just run it like an ordinary linux executable, e.g. `./deviceQuery` (assuming you are in the directory where the deviceQuery sample/executable is located, and assuming you have already built the samples).  If you are trying to compile the deviceQuery sample, follow the instructions [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-linux/index.html#compiling-examples).

Comment: newbie mistake there. Thank you very much that was the issue.

Comment: @RobertCrovella I recommend posting that (or something like it) as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nvcc` is not used to run programs.  It is a [compiler driver](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html).  When a cuda program gets compiled/linked/built, it becomes an ordinary executable.

We use ordinary methods (based on OS) to run these executables.

When setting up a machine for CUDA usage, it may be useful to refer to the [setup instructions](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-linux/index.html) for the OS type.  These documents explain how to build (compile) the CUDA samples as well.